# How to check for variable value if it is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I need to check for a value of an object field and depending on that I want to set an `ReactiveVar` variable. 
But this field is just an optional one, so maybe it doesn't exists at all. What is the correct way to check the value?

If I would just use `var result = (data.profile.anyField == 'something' )` I would get an error as I can't use `anyField` of `undefined`, if profile isn't set.

So I would do it like this, but I think it can be done a little bit smarter and shorter:

```
var modus;
if (Data.profile) modus = (Data.profile.anyField == 'something') ? 'setValue' : '';
else modus = '';

this.modus = new ReactiveVar(modus);
```

And the second question is if it is correct to set the value of `modus` to an empty string? The result should be like this:

```
this.modus = new ReactiveVar('setValue'); // if modus is true
this.modus = new ReactiveVar();           // if modus is false
```

Comment: What does the `ReativeVar` do? It depends on that if you can or can't pass in an empty string. You could do `var modus = data && data.profile && data.profile.anyField == 'something' ? 'setValue' : '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

A one-liner:

```
new ReactiveVar(Data.profile && Data.profile.anyField == 'something' ? 'setValue' : '');
```

Question 2:

Replace the empty string with `undefined`